# Generate auth token from Azure AD B2C by using Web API Core Login Endpoint

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api, asp.net-core-6.0

I’m trying to get the Azure AD B2C AUTH token through login Endpoint in Web API Core 6.
Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

This article uses a sample ASP.NET web application that calls a web API to illustrate how to add Azure Active Directory B2C (Azure AD B2C) authentication to your web applications - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/configure-authentication-sample-web-app-with-api?tabs=visual-studio

To get an access token ,use
GET

```
https://<tenant-name>.b2clogin.com/<tenant-name>.onmicrosoft.com/<policy- name>/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id=<application-ID>
&nonce=anyRandomValue
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&scope=<application-ID-URI>/<scope-name>
```

&response_type=code

ref docs - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/access-tokens

Then Configure tokens in Azure Active Directory B2C - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/configure-tokens?pivots=b2c-user-flow

Hope this will help you .
Thanks